# Hibernate List<Object[]> to especific object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I don't know if the tittle is clear, but I am going to try to make myself as clear as possible.
This is my scenario,
I have a class called User:

```
@Entity(name="User_table")
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    int userId;

    String userName;

    String userMessage;


//    public User(String userName, String userMessage)
//      {
//          this.userName= userName;
//          this.userMessage = userMessage;
//      }
//  public User(){}

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserMessage() {
        return userMessage;
    }
    public void setUserMessage(String userMessage) {
        this.userMessage = userMessage;
    }

}
```

Related to that table:

```
  mysql> select * from User_table;
+--------+-------------+
| userId |  | userName |
+--------+-------------
|     71 | | Dani     |
|     72 | | Dani     |
+--------++------------
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And what I want is to select all the objects from User_table, where userName = Dani.
So, what I do is this:

```
public List<Object> HotelesNombre(String name) {

        int i = 0;
        User user = null;
        SessionFactory sf = open();
        Session ss = sf.openSession();
        ss.beginTransaction();
        Query query = ss.createQuery("select userId, userName from User_table where userName = :id ");
        query.setParameter("id", name);
        List<Object> list = query.list();
        if (list.size() != 0) {
            ss.getTransaction().commit();
            ss.close();
            return list;
        } else {
            ss.getTransaction().commit();
            ss.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I use List instead of List because I am selecting a part of the object User (not the whole) and List wouldn't work.

So, for testing, in the main class I have:

```
public class HibernateMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int status;

        int i=0;

        Manager manager = new Manager();

        status = manager.creaUsuario("Dani", "pollo");

        //User user = manager.buscaHotel(71);

        List<Object> list = manager.HotelesNombre("Dani");

        System.out.println(list.get(0).getUserName());

        if (list.size() >0){

            for (Object v : list){


                System.out.println(v.getUserName());
            i++;

            }



        }


//      if (user !=null){
//      
//      System.out.println(user.getUserName());
//      }

    }

}
```

I have problem in the lines: `System.out.println(v.getUserName());` and `System.out.println(v.getUserName());`
I can't use the methods in the User Class as v is not a User, so.... how could I do what I want¿? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get back for such a query is a `List<Object[]>`, i.e. a list which contains arrays of objects. Each array is a row returned by the query. And since the query selects `userId` and `userName`, each array contains two elements, the user ID (an `Integer` instance), and the user name (a `String` instance).

Note that, unless you have a huge number of columns, representing a massive amount of information (i.e. blobs), in this table, what you're doing is a premature optimization. You'd better simply use `select u from User u where ...`, and get back a `List<User>`.

Comment: I can't do that,if I do that: </br>`Query query = ss.createQuery("select userId, userName from User_table where userName = :id ");
  query.setParameter("id", name);
  List<User> list = query.list();` I got this error: <br/> **[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.arpit.javapostsforlearning.User** <br/>  This is the reason I use List<Object[]>

Comment: You can't do what? Have you read my answer. It precisely says that such a query does **not** return a `List<User>`, but a `List<Object[]>`. Re-read it. If you want a `List<User>`, the query must retrieve users: `select u from User u ...`

Comment: Can you please write the whole query¿? I think that the select u from User u where..... is confusing me, I don't know if you mean User or User_table, thankss

Comment: I didn't notice you had given a name `User_table` to your entity. So yes, it should be `User_table`. That makes things pretty unreadable and confusing, though. Why not use the default name: `User`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, names could be better. <br/>. I think what you are trying to tell me is what I am already trying? Doing this? `select userId, userName from User_table where userName = :id` and returning a List<User> list¿? Because.... I am not able to do that, because the answer is not an object User. Sorry because I think I am getting something wrong probably. If you could write me exacly what you mean would be perfect, thank you for your patience.

Comment: I have written everything in my answer. If you want a List<User>, use select u from User_table u. NOT select userId, userName. Such a query is valid but it doesn't return User instances. It returns arrays of objects, each array containing a user ID and a user name. I don't know how I could be clearer.

Comment: Yess !!! It works, I think you where trying to short saying select "u", I don't really know how it works, why does it returns User instances and the other query doesn't, Thank you very much